# grep of a shell variable finds nothing

Tags: shell, shell-script, grep

I have some problem with grep. I wrote a script which need to find some numbers from a list (file name *ContigsNames*) in a database. I wrote the following script:

```
file=ContigsNames
while IFS=' ' read -r f1 f2
do
    grep '$f1' /data/databases/fasta/lizih/metagenemark_predictions.faa 
    #grep 1703496 /data/databases/fasta/lizih/metagenemark_predictions.faa
done < "$file"
```

As a check I enter a grep line with specific number which is in the list and it works great! so seems like it has some problem with the '$f1'. When I'm doing echo "$f1", it printed the right numbers with no problems.

What might be the problem? Might it be related to 'string' type instead of number?

Comment: change '$f1' by "$f1" in grep-line

Comment: Please also give us an example of the `ContigsNames` file as well as the fasta file you are parsing.

Answer (score 3):

You put single quotes around `$f1` which causes that not to be expanded, you should use double quotes. Depending on the value of `f1` it could be interpret as an option as Stephane indicated (instead of a regular expression), so you have to be explicit about this:

```
file=ContigsNames
while IFS=' ' read -r f1 f2
do
    grep -Fe "$f1" /data/databases/fasta/lizih/metagenemark_predictions.faa 
    #grep 1703496 /data/databases/fasta/lizih/metagenemark_predictions.faa
done < "$file"
```

Comment: Thanks! but even this:grep "$f1" /data/databases/fasta/lizih/metagenemark_predictions.faa doesn't work

Comment: @lizi And what is the error?

Comment: `$f1` is taken either as a _regular expression_ or an _option_ depending on whether it starts with `-` or not. Use `grep -Fe "$f1" /data/databases/fasta/lizih/metagenemark_predictions.faa` for it to be taken as a fixed string to look for in each line of the file.

Comment: @lizi I updated the answer according to Stephane's comment. The problem might be in the content of the `ContigsNames` file. Can you retry and provide any errors if it still doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks to all of you! I still have the problem. I don't have any error it just doesn't bring back any results (except printing the "$f1" as i asked in 'echo'). Example for the contigName is just number like 1703496. I had the -Fe, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: @lizi extend/update your question with a real part from ContigNames (e.g. 5 lines) and some real lines from the `.faa` file (including some that match and some that don't)